# How do you bind an enum to a dependency property to a combobox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, enums

I have read several articles and stackoverflow posts, but I am still a bit stuck with how to make this work.

I have an enum list that I want to bind to a dependency property, which is then bound to a combobox. When I load the program, the combobox is empty.

Once this is working, I want to display the name in the box (i.e. accessory) and the hex as the value.

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BodyTypeFlags}" />
```

**C#:**

```
public enum BodyTypeFlagsTS4
{
    Accessory = 0x0000000A,
    Blush = 0x00000020
}

public BodyTypeFlagsTS4 BodyTypeFlags
{
    get { return (BodyTypeFlagsTS4)GetValue(BodyTypeFlagsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BodyTypeFlagsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyTypeFlagsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("BodyTypeFlags", typeof(BodyTypeFlagsTS4),
    typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(BodyTypeFlagsTS4)));
```

**Edit:** 
I have done as suggested and I can now see the list of enum items in the combo box. I have two problems:

1. If I keep the enum as is (Name = Hex) then when I click the test button nothing surfaces.
2. If I remove the = hex part (so, it just has Accessory and Blush) then the test button will come back with Accessory - every time. Even when I have blush selected. (I don't want to change the enum format, but this tells me that the two way binding isn't working.)

   ```
   public BodyTypeFlagsTS4 BodyTypes
   {
       get { return (BodyTypeFlagsTS4)GetValue(BodyTypesProperty); }
       set { SetValue(BodyTypesProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyTypesProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("BodyTypes", typeof(BodyTypeFlagsTS4), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata());

   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
       {
           System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(System.Enum.GetName(typeof(BodyTypeFlagsTS4), this.BodyTypes));
       }));
   }
   ```

Comment: ItemsSource can be bound to property of type `IEnumerable` only, you can't bind it to enum. Second, why do you need Dependency Property at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:
[Zip with solution](http://1drv.ms/10sW7IK)

In general you must wrap your enum with object.
Look the commented out code to see how to retrieve enum's names.

The part of the XAML code:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="tools"
                            MethodName="GetValues"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:Tool" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbTools"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource tools}}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ToolType, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Answers on StackOverflow are meant to be self-contained and permanent. You should put code right into the answer instead of providing a temporary link which will die in a month.

Comment: I am getting this error: The name "BodyTypeFlagsEnum" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:S4S" - But I clearly have it referenced at the top: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:S4S". It is also very much in that namespace in the c#. Any ideas?

Comment: You've named enum BodyTypeFlagsTS4 in the question. Please check enum name. In XAML you are referencing local as xmlns:local="clr-namespace:S4S" if your app namespace is declared like `code`namespace S4S`code`

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. (It seems like a known bug with VS that was causing it.) Is the a reason why the enum items aren't loaded in the combobox in the same order as I have them? (I had them in alphabetical order, but they're not anymore.)

Comment: Also, System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(System.Enum.GetName(typeof(BodyTypeFlagsTS4), this.BodyTypes)); comes back empty

Comment: could you provide your project?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a list of available values for the `ComboBox`. For example:

```
public BodyTypeFlagsTS4[] AvailableBodyTypeFlags
{
    get { return (BodyTypeFlagsTS4[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(BodyTypeFlagsTS4)); }
}
```

Then bind your `ComboBox` to the list:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableBodyTypeFlags}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding BodyTypeFlags}" />
```

And you don't actually need dependency properties. Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your view-model is enough.